# How to compute win/loss percentage in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, math

I found a win, loss, percentage calculator in the forums. The form has a PLACE FOR INPUT

```
Team Braves 
WINS = 96
LOSS 66
```

a button Compute Percentage
and a text box it should read Braves won 59.259 percent of games.
The program in the forums does not work. Does any one know how to do this? The math should be wins / wins+loss * 100. Pleas HELP 
This is in V B

Answer (score 3):

Aren't you forgetting the parentheses?

```
wins / (wins + losses) * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking specifically for that format of number, Double.ToString() can format that for you:

```
Textbox.Text = ((wins / (wins + losses)) * 100).ToString("#0.###")
```

Comment: What would the code look like? This?                                  .Private sub btnCompute(""""") Handles btnpercentage.Click           .TextBox.Text = ((Wins / (wins + losses)) * 100) ToString("#0.###)

Comment: No idea what 'btnCompute("""")' is supposed to mean, but the code that I originally gave was complete. Just change the variable names

Comment: This is still not working. My program starts off as btncompute ("""""") btnpercentage. How do I get it to do this? Add num1+num2 / num1 by the total of num 1 + num2 then times it by 100?